# IPIP tunnel speed decreases if idle

Tags: linux, debian, networking, deb

I've set up an IPIP tunnel on 2 deb9 hosts for public IP routing and it kinda works. I can reach both ends, but if I let it idle for a bit, the speed decreases. After a while I can't even reach it anymore. If I send data (e.g. ping) through the tunnel from the host, the IPs are routed to, it wakes up again. What could be causing this?

OT:
I've tried GRE tunnels as well, but that just doesn't work as it should. It delivers 1.5mbit/s speeds on a gigabit link.

Comment: MTU/Keepalive issues. and having the TCP  control/negotiation algorithms being applied twice (outside/inside the tunnel). Those are known limitations, not specific to Linux

Comment: And what could I do about the second part? I've tried changing the MTU, but that didn't help (atleast with the values i tried). I am running a ping session as a keepalive, but that only keeps it alive, the speed still goes down.

Comment: They are known issues of doing IP in top of IP, or even SCP on top of SSH+IP....I have no workarounds for you that work over the long term. Maybe using IPsec will improve the situation.